# Ubsan index out of bounds error and acpi errorwhen booting

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, bios, acpi

My system was fine for a long time but then for some reason my files app disappeared so I restarted my computer and now it will not boot. I can go into the virtual terminals (I think that is what they are called) and type commands but cannot boot into the gui.
Things that I have tried (semi In order)

1. Install the latest Nvidia driver
2. Install nvidia driver 510
3. Purge all packages that contain nvidia and install 510
   Attached are the errors and system info[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRl6J.jpg)
   [neofetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeXYO.jpg)[image: errors 2]

Comment: the ubsan error is harmless. It’s due to the wrong size being declared on some arrays in UVM.

Comment: This looks like a video driver incompatibility … Try purging Nvida drivers and then let Ubuntu choose the recommended driver(s) with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and reboot to see if that worked.

Comment: I I tried auto install. But it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old, but I did find out the issue.
I was trying to remove a gnome package that I did not need, but I accidentally deleted every gnome package, including my desktop environment. I tried re-installing gnome, but it looked different from what I was used to, so I just used it to move all my files to an external drive. I then reinstalled Ubuntu and now everything is fine.